# Attempting to align text to the style of a SNES game

Tags: html, css

Let's make a long story, short.

I want the text in this...

[image]

To look more like this...

[image]

And I mean the alignment of it when I type. In the layout I have, the first line is longer, and the second is shorter. It looks pretty ugly with those dots there.

The site I'm using is very limited with the way their code works, which kinda sucks. But here's my code so far.

```
<div style="width:100%;height:550px;background:url(https://www.vizzed.com/smd/photo_album_pics/fullsize/35979-1555716669.gif) no-repeat;background-size:100% 100%;">
  <div style="width:67%;height:25%;background-color:transparent;position:relative;left:135px;position:relative;top: 365px;border-style:hidden;overflow: auto;border-width:0px;padding: 5px">
    <p style="font-size: 26pt;font-family: Arial Black;font-weight: bold;text-align: center;word-spacing: 10px;letter-spacing;6px;color: black; -webkit-text-fill-color: white; -webkit-text-stroke-width: 2.3px; -webkit-text-stroke-color: black; }">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understand exactly your problem, but if you just want to control where to cut the sentence, you could use the `<br>` tag.